# Checking if field contains multiple string in sql server

Tags: sql, t-sql, query-optimization, user-defined-functions

I am working on a sql database which will provide with data some grid. The grid will enable filtering, sorting and paging but also there is a strict requirement that users can enter free text to a text input above the grid for example
'Engine 1001 Requi' and that the result will contain only rows which in some columns contain all the pieces of the text. So one column may contain Engine, other column may contain 1001 and some other will contain Requi.

I created a technical column (let's call it myTechnicalColumn) in the table (let's call it myTable) which will be updated each time someone inserts or updates a row and it will contain all the values of all the columns combined and separated with space.

Now to use it with entity framework I decided to use a table valued function which accepts one parameter @searchQuery and it will handle it like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION myFunctionName(@searchText NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS @Result TABLE
( ... here come columns )
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @searchToken TokenType
        INSERT INTO @searchToken(token) SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@searchText,' ')
    
        DECLARE @searchTextLength INT
        SET @searchTextLength = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @searchToken)

        INSERT INTO @Result
        SELECT
        ... here come columns
        FROM myTable
        WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @searchToken WHERE CHARINDEX(token, myTechnicalColumn) > 0) = @searchTextLength
        RETURN;
    END
```

Of course the solution works fine but it's kinda slow. Any hints how to improve its efficiency?

Comment: Will splitting on spaces suffice, e.g. `'Repair brakes,engine,bonnet.'` won't match `'Engine'`? Do you need to handle _stemming_, e.g. should `'drive'` match `'drove'`? Do you need weighting, e.g. if all search words are found in a single column is that a "better" result than if no column contains more than one search word?

Comment: And if you don't use tokens on both sides of the search you'll have a search for `'gin'` match `'engine'`.

Comment: We assume that the query string is sanitized like, no commas, just words and numbers separated by single space. And answering the second question - yes this is the requirement: 'gin' should match 'engine' and also 'ginandtonic'. Stemming is not a requirement, so 'drive' should not match 'drove'. Weighting is not a requirement: there is a match or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an inline Table Valued Function, which should be quite a lot faster.

This would be a direct translation of your current code

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION myFunctionName(@searchText NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
(
    WITH searchText AS (
        SELECT value token
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(@searchText,' ') s(token)
    )
    SELECT
        ... here come columns
    FROM myTable t
    WHERE (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM searchText
        WHERE CHARINDEX(s.token, t.myTechnicalColumn) > 0
    ) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM searchText)
);

GO
```

---

You are using a form of query called *Relational Division Without Remainder* and there are other ways to cut this cake:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION myFunctionName(@searchText NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
(
    WITH searchText AS (
        SELECT value token
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(@searchText,' ') s(token)
    )
    SELECT
        ... here come columns
    FROM myTable t
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM searchText
        WHERE CHARINDEX(s.token, t.myTechnicalColumn) = 0
    )
);

GO
```

This may be faster or slower depending on a number of factors, you need to test.

Comment: Thank you - I already managed to figure out the same solution, but still you get full credit.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no data to test, i am not sure if the following will solve your issue:

```
-- Replace the last INSERT portion
INSERT INTO @Result
   SELECT
        ... here come columns
   FROM myTable T
   JOIN @searchToken S ON CHARINDEX(S.token, T.myTechnicalColumn) > 0
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint but unfortunately the resultset is different since we join.